# Warning message: 'GUID' field of 'GUID' item is skipped: field name is missed

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-search, paas, index

In all of our environments, any time there is an index update to our Azure Search indexes, we see the following WARN message logged repeatedly (many thousands of times):

> 06:11:06 WARN  [Index=sitecore_web_index] 'GUID' field of 'GUID' item is skipped: the field name is missed.

This message is logged because we have specified included fields for our search indexes to work around the Azure Search 1000 field limit, but not every item that we index contains every field we want to index.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Sitecore Support about this issue and they responded promptly with a patch to resolve it.

They have asked that it not be shared publicly, but you can retrieve the patch by referencing reference number **253826**.